# Incrementing Multidimensional Hashes in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

As I iterate through the rows of a mysql table, there are 2 values in each table (x,y) that I need to see what interval those two values fall between.

For example if x=-21.1 and y=52.4, x would be in the -30..-20 interval and y would be in the 50..60 interval.

So based on these intervals, I would have a hash or something containing that interval combination (-30..-20 and 50..60) and increment it by one. Then I would go through the rest of the rows in the mysql table and do the same so I have a count of all occurances of the interval combinations.

There will be 36X36 combinations (interval -180..180, divided in 10s). I think this is supposed to be done by using multidimensional hashes, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

How about doing it in MySQL itself?

```
SELECT FLOOR(x/10)*10, FLOOR(y/10)*10, COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FLOOR(x/10), FLOOR(y/10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works quite well and easily implementable in my Perl code :)